# C# HTTP Request Parser

Tags: c#, .net, http

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Raw HTTP Request into HTTPWebRequest Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318506/converting-raw-http-request-into-httpwebrequest-object)

I've got a custom HTTP server written in C# which gives me the raw HTTP request...

```
GET /ACTION=TEST HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2009042316 Firefox/3.0.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
```

Is there something in the .NET framework that I can use to parse it or do I have to do it by hand?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean you wish to convert a stream of bytes into a HttpRequest instance? I've never come across it, but I imagine there must be some code in the framework that does it (inside HttpWebRequest somewhere perhaps).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318506/converting-raw-http-request-into-httpwebrequest-object). Apparently there is no built-in way to do it.

Comment: ah, you beat me to it. thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

Check out [HttpMachine](https://github.com/bvanderveen/httpmachine) - a component of the [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com/) HTTP server for dotNET. HttpMachine is a callback driven HTTP parser.

To wet your appetite, here's the [IHttpParserHandler](https://github.com/bvanderveen/httpmachine/blob/b658bc9b64436027c572c291e9ebb6e729d82721/HttpMachine/IHttpParserHandler.cs) interface:

```
using System
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HttpMachine
{
    public interface IHttpParserHandler
    {
        void OnMessageBegin(HttpParser parser);
        void OnMethod(HttpParser parser, string method);
        void OnRequestUri(HttpParser parser, string requestUri);
        void OnFragment(HttpParser parser, string fragment);
        void OnQueryString(HttpParser parser, string queryString);
        void OnHeaderName(HttpParser parser, string name);
        void OnHeaderValue(HttpParser parser, string value);
        void OnHeadersEnd(HttpParser parser);
        void OnBody(HttpParser parser, ArraySegment<byte> data);
        void OnMessageEnd(HttpParser parser);
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this in a transparent proxy of mine. When it works, it works great. But when it doesn't, it dies a terrible death. One misplaced character and it's dead. Great, but does not fail gracefully.