# C#: How to execute a HTTP request using sockets?

Tags: c#, sockets

I am trying to make a `HTTP request` using sockets. My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
class test
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        string hostName = "127.0.0.1";
        int hostPort = 9887;
        int response = 0;

        IPAddress host = IPAddress.Parse(hostName);
        IPEndPoint hostep = new IPEndPoint(host, hostPort);
        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sock.Connect(hostep);

        string request_url = "http://127.0.0.1/register?id=application/vnd-fullphat.test&title=My%20Test%20App";
        response = sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request_url));
        response = sock.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n"));

        bytes = sock.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
        page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine(page);
        sock.Close();
    }
}
```

Now when I execute the above code nothing happens whereas when I enter my `request_url` in browser I get a notification from Snarl saying that `Application Registered` and the response I get from browser is

```
SNP/2.0/0/OK/556
```

The response I get from my code is `SNP/3.0/107/BadPacket`.

So, what is wrong with my code.

[Snarl Request format specification](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/snarlwin/index.php?title=SNP_2.0_API)

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use Sockets rather than, say, `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`?

Comment: or Webclient for that matter...

Comment: No there is no specific reason. Actually I was not aware of `HttpCLient or Webclient`. But anyways I will like to understand what is wrog with my above code.

Comment: Is it necessary to send the additional "\r\n" after sending the primary url? If you don't send it with the browser, then try removing it in code, so as to replicate exactly the same behaviour as your browser.

Comment: Also, as jgauffin has said, you will have to include content-length, host, etc. If you don't want to do that, use a high-level object to send such as HttpWebRequest.

Comment: HTTP does not simply work by sending the URL to the server; you need more request headers. The ones that are required for a valid request are written out in the HTTP RFC (2616), and the Snarl Protocol over HTTP might even require more data. Please try to capture some requests using Fiddler for example, so you can see what data is being exchanged.

Comment: You can see structure code analog at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812927/http-1-1-request-message-goes-to-infinitive-cycle-while-getting-result-through

Comment: Might just be a transcription error to SO, but `bytes`, `bytesReceived`, and `page` are all undefined in the code above.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must include content-length and double new line in the end to indicate end of header.

```
var request = "GET /register?id=application/vnd-fullphat.test&title=My%20Test%20App HTTP/1.1\r\n" + 
    "Host: 127.0.0.1\r\n" +
    "Content-Length: 0\r\n" +
    "\r\n";
```

The HTTP 1.1 specification can be found here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: Thanks mate. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 17):

I know nothing about SNP. Your code is a bit confusing on the receive part. I have used the example bellow to send and read server response for an HTTP GET request. First let's take a look at the request and then examine the response.

HTTP GET request :

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html
User-Agent: CSharpTests

string - "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nUser-Agent: CSharpTests\r\n\r\n"
```

Server HTTP response header :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 07 Jul 2013 17:13:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16
Last-Modified: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 11:28:59 GMT
ETag: \"ca-4d922b19fd4c0\"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 202
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html

string - "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Sun, 07 Jul 2013 17:13:10 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16\r\nLast-Modified: Sat, 30 Mar 2013 11:28:59 GMT\r\nETag: \"ca-4d922b19fd4c0\"\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nContent-Length: 202\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
```

I have purposely ommited the body of the server response, because we already know it is exactly 202 bytes, as specified by Content-Length in the response header.

A look over the HTTP specification will reveal that an HTTP header ends with an empty new line ("\r\n\r\n"). So we just need to search for it.

Let's see some code in action. Assume a variable socket of type System.Net.Sockets.Socket.

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Connect("127.0.0.1", 80);
string GETrequest = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept: text/html\r\nUser-Agent: CSharpTests\r\n\r\n";
socket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GETrequest));
```

We have sent the request to the server, let's receive and correctly parse the response.

```
bool flag = true; // just so we know we are still reading
string headerString = ""; // to store header information
int contentLength = 0; // the body length
byte[] bodyBuff = new byte[0]; // to later hold the body content
while (flag)
{
// read the header byte by byte, until \r\n\r\n
byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
socket.Receive(buffer, 0, 1, 0);
headerString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
if (headerString.Contains("\r\n\r\n"))
{
    // header is received, parsing content length
    // I use regular expressions, but any other method you can think of is ok
    Regex reg = new Regex("\\\r\nContent-Length: (.*?)\\\r\n");
    Match m = reg.Match(headerString);
    contentLength = int.Parse(m.Groups[1].ToString());
    flag = false;
    // read the body
    bodyBuff = new byte[contentLength];
    socket.Receive(bodyBuff, 0, contentLength, 0);
}
}
Console.WriteLine("Server Response :");
string body = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bodyBuff);
Console.WriteLine(body);
socket.Close();
```

This is probably the worst method to do this in C#, there are tons of classes to handle HTTP requests and responses in .NET, but still if you needed it, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is not correct. According to [wikipedia, a HTTP Get request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Client_request) has to look like:

```
string request = "GET /register?id=application/vnd-fullphat.test&title=My%20Test%20App HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1\r\n";
```

Comment: I am still getting `SNP/3.0/107/BadPacket`

Comment: It sounds like you need something more in your request, like Connection, Accept or maybe Accept-Encoding. What PVitt showed is a minimal request, though that might not be enough for your specific protocol. Try working with WebClient as suggested above and see if that works so you are sure that the API works as it should.

Comment: According to the accepted answer, it must've been `Content-Length`.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum requirement for a HTTP request is 
"GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" (if removing the Host is allowed).
But in SNARL, you must input the content-length (what I most heard).

So,

```
        Socket sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        sck.Connect(ip, port);
        sck.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THE HTTP REQUEST HEADER"));
        Console.WriteLine("SENT");
        string message = null;
        byte[] bytesStored = new byte[sck.ReceiveBufferSize];
        int k1 = sck.Receive(bytesStored);
        for (int i = 0; i < k1; i++)
        {
            message = message + Convert.ToChar(bytesStored[i]).ToString();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(message); // PRINT THE RESPONSE
```

I tested on several sites and it works perfectly. If it didn't work, then you should fix it by adding more header (most likely solution).