# Using TTL without ping

Tags: c#, ping

Are there any ways to use Time-to-live value with a tcp or webrequest? In some networks icmp and echo packets are not allowed. I need a way to limit a request with specific TTL value.

Comment: TTL is a parameter to PING (and others) - it doesn't make sense to use by itself. What command do you want to limit with TTL?

Comment: TTL is a field in IP headers. I don't see why this is a bad question. The answer may well be "No, there's no way to do that", but I don't think the question deserves to be closed.

Comment: The question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: This question could be about how to manipulate IPHeaders in C#, which is on topic

Comment: @JamesBarrass Unfortunately it doesn't mention anything about code other than the tag so as it stands, it's very off topic.

Comment: I'm trying to secure my licensing library. I want to add a lan redirection check. A packet with 1 or 2 ttl cant access the internet, if this low ttl request returns a success response, this means target host is redirecting to another local pc or localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Ttl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.ttl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to set the TTL if you are creating the socket yourself. I suppose you could do this if you want to make a web request over it: [C#: How to execute a HTTP request using sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862890/c-how-to-execute-a-http-request-using-sockets)

Comment: Am I being voted down for a bad answer or because I disagreed that the question should be closed? The question asks how to set TTL on a TCP request or a web request in C#. I'm happy to improve the answer if given feedback on it.