# C# Convert HttpResponse body to readable content

Tags: c#, http, request, decode, encode

I'm using a Http Sniffer to capture http message on my Android phone. Each request the app save two file:

1.File named "rawdata.bin": The raw http response message, contains http response header and http response body.
[image]
2.File named "body.json" An JSON file contains the http response body data. This data is humand friendly text.
[image]

My problems is: I want to get the JSON data from the file named "rawdata.bin" directly in C#. But it's look like encoded, how do I convert it ?

[image]

**This is what I tried**

I opened the file named "rawdata.bin" with Notepad++ and remove header part (include the blank line between header and body) then save to file named body.hcy

This is my code, but it doesn't work as expected.

[image]

**This is my raw http response packet file**: file[.]io/YdO53cAU26Up

Comment: I assume you are writing the loaded data directly to the response body as string and you are converting the loaded data to UTF8 before?

Comment: The clue is; "Content-Encoding: gzip". You need to deflate it. But you haven't posted any code that describes what you are actually doing.... It's a pity that the dotnet runtime parser is not reusable https://stackoverflow.com/a/59314866/4139809

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I just updated my code. Please help me bro.

Comment: I think the usual `HttpClient` Http/1.1 response parsing happens [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnection.cs#L589). which you might be able to copy.

Comment: This is my packet file, please help me to decode the body: file[.]io/YdO53cAU26Up

Comment: Do you have to do this in C#? Does your http sniffer have any option to decode the payload? Are you trying to do this once, or do you need build this into some other application?